# SQL - Calculating sum of variable updated values

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum

I'm new to SQL and I have the following problem.
I want to sum total number of errors that are reaching my device.

So, suppose I have inside `my_table` variables with names `SeqErr` and `TotalSeqErr`.
I initialized them to `0` and verified it, but when I do the following:

```
  UPDATE my_table
  SET
  ...
    SeqErr         =      COALESCE(SeqErr, 0) + 1,
    TotalSeqErr    =      SeqErr,
  ...
```

I see that when I retrieve this table it is coming with the following values:
`SeqErr = 1` , `TotalSeqErr = 0` (i.e. `SeqErr` was updated but `TotalSeqErr` is using old `SeqErr` value instead of updated one).

How can I solve this issue?
**Note: Probably there is issue similar to mine here but I couldn't find one.**

Comment: I'm using `PostgreSQL` as my SQL database if this is what you meant.

Comment: You will need to run that UPDATE at least twice to see a non-zero value in totalseqerr (but that assignment should also use `coalesce()`) https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1a6f1fad04f3e42bbdc2243c66232ce7

Comment: Btw: `seqerr` is not a "variable", it's called a column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your `TotalSeqErr` to use the "new" `SeqErr` you could just update it the same way you update `SeqErr`:

```
...
SeqErr         =      COALESCE(SeqErr, 0) + 1,
TotalSeqErr    =      COALESCE(SeqErr, 0) + 1,
...
```

You could imagine that  update is done all at once not line by line. So what you have in the right side of the equal refers to the old values even though you set them to a new value a line above.

Comment: So there is no way to do so inside one query?   
(In case I want `TotalSeqErr` to get `SeqErr` updated variable I will need it to be inside another query)

Comment: @ms_stud: that **is** one query.

Comment: Added an explanation to my answer, let me know if that helps or if you require extra informaton. Note that `COALESCE(SeqErr, 0) + 1` is not another query, it is another expression.

Answer (score 1):

The way an update works is that the references on the "left" (i.e. the `set` columns) refer to the *new* record.  The references on the "right" (i.e. the expressions) refer to the old values.  This is how SQL is defined.  I only know of one database that does not support the standard behavior, MySQL/MariaDB.

One method is to repeat the expression:

```
UPDATE my_table
  SET . . .
      SeqErr      =  COALESCE(SeqErr, 0) + 1,
      TotalSeqErr =  COALESCE(SeqErr, 0) + 1,
      ...;
```

Assuming your table has a primary key, you can also simplify the `SET` logic by using a `FROM` clause and a lateral join:

```
UPDATE my_table t
      SET . . .
          SeqErr      =  v.new_SeqErr,
          TotalSeqErr =  v.new_SeqErr,
          ...
    FROM my_table t2 CROSS JOIN LATERAL
         (VALUES (COALESCE(t2.SeqErr, 0) + 1)
         ) v(new_seqerr)
    WHERE t2.<primary key> = t.<primary key>
```